# Converting C# Byte [,] to np array / image in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am using a python wrapper API for a camera with 12-bit resolution. The return of the function is a byte array

```
byte [,] getLastImageAs2Darray()
```

in python I am converting it to a numpy array as so:

```
image_csharp = getLastImageAs2Darray()
np_arr = np.frombuffer(image_csharp, dtype=np.uint16) # 16 for 12-bit resolution
np_img = np.reshape(np_arr, (1, width, height)
```

For some reason, whenever I write this array to a file or read it (even display), it always seems to split up the lower 8 bits and top 8 bits, for instance:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Mann.jpg

Is there some way I need to handle this byte array to convert it properly into an np array.